# How to set permission to all users in IBM queue manager/queue channel and queues

Tags: ibm-mq

How can I set permission to queue manager/queue channel/queues in IBM mq without specifying the user? i need to give the permission to all the users

Comment: Did my answer help resolve your question.  If so please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

On UNIX and Linux systems you can grant permission to all users by granting permission on the special group `nobody`.

From the Knowledge Center page "[Principals and groups](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014100_.htm)"

> You can change the authorization in the nobody group to grant access to WebSphere® MQ resources to users without specific authorizations.